# PHP Two different buttons send same data

Tags: php, html, button, send

I have two different buttons. One for deleting user and the other is for Changing email address. The problem is that clicking the change email button will actually delete the user from database.

**header.php**

```
<?php
session_start();


$cookie_name = "LoginSystem";
$cookie_value = "Valid";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">


  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Enrol site for activites">
  <meta name="keywords" content="enrol, activities, school, hobby, college, login, register">
  <meta name="author" content="Gyorgy Hadhazy">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


</head>
<body>



<header> 
    <nav>
        <div class="main-wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="media.php">MEDIA</a></li>
                <li><a href="activities.php">ACTIVITIES</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="nav-login">
                <?php 
                    if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
                        echo '
                        <form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
                            <button type="submit" name="submit">Logout</button>
                        </form>
                        ';
                       echo '<form action="deleteusr.php" method="POST">
                            <button type="submit" name="delete">Delete User</button>
                            <input type="hidden" name="user_uid" value="'. $_SESSION['u_id'].'"
                            </form>';


                    } else{
                        echo '
                        <form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="POST">
                            <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="StudentID/email">
                            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="password">
                            <button type="submit" name="submit">LOGIN</button>
                        </form>
                        <a href="signup.php">SIGN UP</a>
                        ';
                    }



                ?>

                <button type="button" onclick="resizeText(1)" name="resizeplus" class="resize-plus">+ Text size</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="resizeText(-1)" name="resizenegative">- Text size</button>  


<script>

function resizeText(multiplier) {
  if (document.body.style.fontSize == "") {
    document.body.style.fontSize = "1.0em";
  }
document.body.style.fontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";
}   
</script>



            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**index.php**

```
    <?php
        include 'header.php';
    ?>


    <style>
        header{
        text-align: center; 
        }
        body{
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>

    <section class="main-container">
        <div class="main-wrapper">
            <h2>HOME</h2>
        <p>Please log in if extra features are not displayed</p>
            <?php


            if (isset($_SESSION['u_email'])) {

                            echo '<form action="changeEmail.php" method="POST">
                                <button type="submit" name="email">Change Email</button> 
                                <input type="text" name="email" value="'. $_SESSION['u_email'].'"
                                </form>'; }


            ?>  
        </div>
    </section>





    <?php
    include 'footer.php';
?>
```

And finally the php file it should call: **changeEmail.php**

```
<?php
    include 'header.php';
?>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "loginsystem";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}



$email = $_SESSION['u_ email'];

$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_email='$email'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I think the issue is in the header.php but I am not exactly sure. If someone would help to point out the issue I would really appreciate it.

HTML code rendered by index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">


  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Enrol site for activites">
  <meta name="keywords" content="enrol, activities, school, hobby, college, login, register">
  <meta name="author" content="Gyorgy Hadhazy">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


</head>
<body>



<header> 
    <nav>
        <div class="main-wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="media.php">MEDIA</a></li>
                <li><a href="activities.php">ACTIVITIES</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="nav-login">

                        <form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
                            <button type="submit" name="submit">Logout</button>
                        </form>
                        <form action="deleteusr.php" method="POST">
                            <button type="submit" name="delete">Delete User</button>
                            <input type="hidden" name="user_uid" value="6"
                            </form>                
                <button type="button" onclick="resizeText(1)" name="resizeplus" class="resize-plus">+ Text size</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="resizeText(-1)" name="resizenegative">- Text size</button>  


<script>

function resizeText(multiplier) {
  if (document.body.style.fontSize == "") {
    document.body.style.fontSize = "1.0em";
  }
document.body.style.fontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";
}   
</script>



            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<style>
    header{
    text-align: center; 
    }
    body{
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<section class="main-container">
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <h2>HOME</h2>
    <p>Please log in if extra features are not displayed</p>
        <form action="changeEmail.php" method="POST">
                            <button type="submit" name="email">Change Email</button> 
                            <input type="text" name="email" value="test11@gmail.com"
                            </form>  
    </div>
</section>






Cookie 'LoginSystem' is set!<br>Value: Valid
```

Image of the actual look:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL41r.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The main issue:**

There are two `<input>` tags missing closing `>` characters. This means the browser is constructing an inaccurate DOM tree. It's doing its best to determine which form you want to submit, but it's picking the wrong one (the delete form).

The first example is in header.php:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_uid" value="'. $_SESSION['u_id'].'"
```

Notice there's no `>` closing that input tag.

And then in index.php:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="'. $_SESSION['u_email'].'"
```

Add closing `>` characters to both of those, and the browser will happily parse the DOM and pick the correct form to submit when you click the button.

**Other issues:**

There are a couple issues in changeEmail.php:

```
$email = $_SESSION['u_ email'];
```

needs to be

```
$email = $_SESSION['u_email'];
```

Otherwise, `$email` will always be an empty string (or some other value you don't want - I'm unsure of `$_SESSIONS`'s behavior), and you'll set all emails to an empty string.

The second issue is your SQL:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_email='$email'";
```

You need to specify which user's email to set, using a `where` clause. Otherwise you're setting every email to the value of `$email`.

In this specific case, you need to get the *new* email address from the posted form data.

```
$new_email = $_POST["email"];
$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_email='$new_email' WHERE user_email='$email'";
```

To be sure you'll get the new `email` form data, remove the `name` attribute from the `button` element - it's not necessary.

Comment: Thanks very much this was very helpful. I am very new to php so I really appreciate the help. Whenever I click to the change email button it still deletes the user. So the changeEmail.php is not being called. Any idea why? Thanks and have a nice day

Comment: Can you post the full HTML of the rendered page?

Comment: I just edited my original post. You can find it at the bottom! Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. Can you post the HTML rendered by index.php?

Comment: I have added the code that I copied straight the browser. I hope this is what you need! I appreciate the effort once again! :)